How to Pass ti (Task Instance) Context to an External Python Task in Airflow
I’m trying to pass the ti (Task Instance) context to an external Python task in Airflow so that I can use xcom_pull and xcom_push within the external task.
Here is a simplified version of my setup:
@task.external_python(
    task_id="task_1",
    provide_context=True,
    **python_task_arguments,
)
def task_1(ti):
    import pandas as pd

    upa_ar_dates = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="A", key="A")
    factors_dates = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="B", key="B")
    ksa_risk_dates = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="C", key="C")

    
    task_1(ti="{{ ti }}"),

I’m running into issues when trying to use ti (Task Instance) in the external Python task:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xcom_pull'

I have tried using get_current_context() to access ti, but I’m not sure if this is the right approach for an external Python task, since I’m getting errors related to the context not being passed correctly.
